# Поиск элементов массива, значения которых начинаются с определенных символов

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив элементы которого только числа в виде дерева кодов

```
$codes = [
    '2'   => '0001002',
    '5'   => '0001002001',
    '21'  => '0001002002',
    '12'  => '0001002001001',
    '42'  => '0001002001001001',
    '555' => '0001002001001002',
    '7'   => '0001007',
    '67'  => '0001008',
    '34'  => '0001008001',
    '56'  => '0001008002',
    '78'  => '0001008003',
    '15'  => '0001008003001',
    '24'  => '0001008003002',
    '13'  => '0001008004',
    '88'  => '0001010',
    '6'   => '0001011',
    '3'   => '0001012',
    ...
    ...
    ...
    'N'   => '0007009001'
]
```

Как мне узнать существует ли элементы в массиве, значения которых начинаются с определенного кода.

Например при проверки на код `0001002`, должен найти все элементы массива значение которых начинаются с `0001002*`, где `*` любое число

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно решить с помощью `array_filter()` и `strpos()`:

```
$codes = [
    '2'   => '0001002',
    '5'   => '0001002001',
    '21'  => '0001002002',
    '12'  => '0001002001001',
    '42'  => '0001002001001001',
    '555' => '0001002001001002',
    '7'   => '0001007',
    '67'  => '0001008',
    '34'  => '0001008001',
    '56'  => '0001008002',
    '78'  => '0001008003',
    '15'  => '0001008003001',
    '24'  => '0001008003002',
    '13'  => '0001008004',
    '88'  => '0001010',
    '6'   => '0001011',
    '3'   => '0001012'
];


$need = '0001002';

$code = array_filter($codes, function($str) use($need){
    return preg_match("~^$need~", $str);
});

var_dump($code);
```

В результате будет массив соответствий:

```
array (size=6)
  2 => string '0001002' (length=7)
  5 => string '0001002001' (length=10)
  21 => string '0001002002' (length=10)
  12 => string '0001002001001' (length=13)
  42 => string '0001002001001001' (length=16)
  555 => string '0001002001001002' (length=16)
```

Comment: почти подошло, вот только если я буду искать код `001002` то он не должен быть найден, так как такой элемент нет который начинается на `001002`, а он сейчас находит. Мне нужно проверка с самого начального символа

Comment: @Xfirab подправил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
$codes = [
    '2'   => '0001002',
    '5'   => '0001002001',
    '21'  => '0001002002',
    '12'  => '0001002001001',
    '42'  => '0001002001001001',
    '555' => '0001002001001002',
    '7'   => '0001007',
    '67'  => '0001008',
    '34'  => '0001008001',
    '56'  => '0001008002',
    '78'  => '0001008003',
    '15'  => '0001008003001',
    '24'  => '0001008003002',
    '13'  => '0001008004',
    '88'  => '0001010',
    '6'   => '0001011',
    '3'   => '0001012',
    ...
    ...
    ...
    'N'   => '0007009001'
]
$aux = '0001002';
foreach ($codes as $code){
    if (substr($code, 0, 6) == $aux) echo $code;
}
```

Ты это хотел?

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 0x000000, 3 => 'green', 4 => 'red');
$key = array_search('red', $array);         // Print $key = 1;
```

array_search --  Осуществляет поиск данного значения в массиве и возвращает соответствующий ключ в случае удачи